# Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be a string, array given while exporting the data in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpexcel

I am using CodeIgniter. I am exporting the data in the excel sheet.

Now What I am doing is, I have `Payment option` and `Payment Details` column.

I have to display the output in the column like

```
if(Payment option == 'a'){
//display array in the column
}
else if(Payment option == 'b')
{
//display array in the column
}
else{
//
}
```

**Expected output**

[image]

I am getting the error

1)

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined offset: 0
Filename: Cell/DefaultValueBinder.php
```

2)

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
Filename: Cell/DefaultValueBinder.php
```

**Export code**

```
public function export_order_list(){
  $object = new PHPExcel();
  $object->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
  $table_columns = array("Customer Name","Email","Mobile no","Alternet no","Payment option","Payment Details","Date of created");
  $column = 0;
  $object->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('1:1')->getFont()->setBold(true);

  foreach($table_columns as $field)
  {
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($column, 1, $field);

   $column++;
  }
  $export_list = $this->Customer_model->export_order_list_model();//getting all data
  $excel_row = 2;
  foreach($export_list as $row)
  {
   $cust_name=$row->c_firstname." " .$row->c_middlename."".$row->c_lastname;
   if ($row->payment_option=='A') {
         $payment_details=array(
          'Account holder name:' => $row->account_holder_name,
          'Account no:'=>$row->e_account_no,
          'Cheque no:'=>$row->cheque_no
         );

   }
   if ($row->payment_option=='b') {
      $payment_details=array(
        'Name On Card:' => $row->c_name_on_card,
        'Card Number:'=>$row->c_card_number,
       'Exp month'=>$row->c_exp_month,
       );
   }
   else{
     $payment_details="";
   }

   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, $cust_name);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $excel_row, $row->c_email_id);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2, $excel_row, $row->c_mobileno);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(3, $excel_row, $row->c_alternetno);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(4, $excel_row, $row->payment_option);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(5, $excel_row, $payment_details);
   $object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(6, $excel_row, $row->c_date_of_added);
   $excel_row++;
  }

  $object_writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Order list.xls"');
        $object_writer->save('php://output');
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this block of code array to string

```
if ($row->payment_option=='A') {
     $payment_details='Account holder name:'.$row->account_holder_name.' Account no:'.$row->e_account_no.' Cheque no:'.$row->cheque_no;
}else if ($row->payment_option=='b') {
     $payment_details='Name On Card:'.$row->c_name_on_card.' Card Number:'.$row->c_card_number.'  Exp month'.$row->c_exp_month;
}else{
     $payment_details="";
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer but if condition is not working. I am getting only the value of b. When I comment elseif then if condition is working.

Comment: in 1st if payment option is "A" is correct or it is "a" ?

Comment: I tried "a" and if I comment elseif condition then if the condition is working.

Comment: so now what problem you face?

Comment: can you please share your database row for 1st true condition means which row data is true in 1st condition?

Comment: I am getting the output in the excel http://prntscr.com/l65zun. Give me some time to check the code again.

Comment: Sure take your own time.

Comment: have you got the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
if(is_array($payment_details)){

    $result = array_map(function($k, $v){
        return "$k=$v";
    }, array_keys($payment_details), array_values($payment_details));

    $payment_details = implode(' ', $result);
}
```

before

```
$object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, $cust_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's not working as I expected output. It's removing the heading. I am getting the output only xyz 1234 12541